Property 'fileUrl' does not exist on type 'ClientUploadedFileData<null>'
const onSubmit= async(values:z.infer) => {
const blob = values.profile_photo;
const hasImageChanged = isBase64Image(blob);
if (hasImageChanged) {
  const imgRes = await startUpload(files);

  if (imgRes && imgRes[0].fileUrl) {
    values.profile_photo = imgRes[0].fileUrl;
  }
}  

}
//the error keeps on coming when i am using fileUrl. Please give a solution. I have used useupload thing
I could not find any solution related to it in the upload thing documentation..

Instead of imgRes[0].fileUrl, use imgRes[0].url
